# z-index for jquery object issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

First off, I am sorry in advance- anyone who reads this is going to hate me.

So, I am currently finishing a webpage for a client. Things are going decently, except I'm having a bit of an issue with the positioning of an element. There is a little contact box that is supposed to slide in from the side when you click on it. The issue is that I basically have had my hands tied, and I have to use wordpress for this page, and this contact box is a plugin that the original author of this page chose. For some reason- this contact box always ends up behind other elements. I tried setting the z-index in the source code of the plugin by finding the name of the variable that is supposed to hold the instance of the slider- and I could not get anything to work (partially because I havent used jquery in a while, and, this isn't my plugin). I tried using the .zIndex function, but, it kept throwing errors. So, I went to CSS. I got the IDs of the wrapper and the actual box itself, and set their z-index to 100. This did nothing, which has left me stumped. Unfortunately, I can only provide links to the site, and a pastebin of the plugin's code- since the source code for the website is huge... and I also dont actually have access to the server- only the WordPress admin page (which doesnt allow me to edit the source of pages)

http://pastebin.com/NX8AnB16 - pastebin of the plugin source
http://buyinghouseinusa.com/ - the site i am currently trying to finish

If anyone could help me figure out what I need to apply the z-index to to make the stupid contact form stay on top, I would be very greatful. I apologize for the inconvenience of not having the actual code offhand (with the exception of what the browser can show me)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: on chrome, the "contact us" button on the left hand side only hides behind the carousel. Only the button hides, not the form itself. It's on top. AND, it seems that when you transition to the next image the "contact" us button is hidden.

Comment: This will help it blend with the button (free aesthetic advice): `.dwpcontact-page {
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}`

Comment: Strange. It did stop hiding behing the slider. However, it still hides behind the top bar, which is also a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` only applies to positioned elements.

Then, in order to make `div.dwp-contact-wrapper{z-index: 2000}` work, you need

```css
div.dwp-contact-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Use this. It's better than mine was.

Comment: Thank you- this has made it stay in front of the slider(slideshow). I don't ever work with wordpress, I kind of got forced into it- so I didn't know what it was applying to the page already, and what it wasn't. I prefer doing these sort of things by hand

that being said, for some reason it still hides behind the navbar on the top. There are around 7-10 nested divs, none of which seem to clearly hold the blue area to the left of the "home" button- which is what blocks the contact button (at least on my chrome)

Comment: @Tony True, it doesn't overlap the navbar because of `#main-header{z-index:99999}`. Either reduce that absurdly huge number, or increase contact's one, or place `#main-header` in another stacking context e.g. adding `#page-container{position:relative; z-index:0}`

Comment: oh my god, I didn't see that. Why the hell did the old designer decide that was a great idea? Well, thank you for finding that. I will try to see if I can get a way to fix that. At the time I don't have access to the actual server, so, I will let my client know what is going on. I'm marking this as the answer